# How to enable unit testing in a Java module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, kotlin

I am new to Android development. I have an android project with two Java modules. I would like to create some unit tests for the two modules.

Comment: You want to create unit test under `app` right?

Comment: I want to create unit tests under the `Module 1` and `Module 2` modules.